# Can I refer to calculated columns within a Linq to Sql query?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have the following schema:

```
product  
- productID (PK)  
- name  
- units  

purchase  
- purchaseID (PF)  
- productID (FK)  
- soldUnits  
- woUnits  

boxContents  
- boxID (PK)  
- puchaseID (FK)  
- count
```

and the following Linq to SQL query:

```
 var qStockLevel = from pr in db.products
    select new
    {
        pr.productID,
        pr.name,
        totalUnits = (from pu in db.purchases
                      where pu.productID == pr.productID
                      select pu).Count() * pr.units,

    sold = (from pr2 in db.products
            join pu in db.purchases on pr.productID equals pu.productID into pp
            where pr2.productID == pr.productID
            from pu2 in pp.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select (int?) pu2.soldUnits ?? 0).Sum(),

    writtenOff = (from pr2 in db.products
                join pu in db.purchases on pr.productID equals pu.productID into pp
                where pr2.productID == pr.productID
                from pu in pp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select (int?)pu.woUnits ?? 0).Sum(),

    onDisplay = (from pr2 in db.products
                join bc in db.boxContents on pr.productID equals bc.purchase.productID into bp
                where pr2.productID == pr.productID
                from bc in bp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select (int?)bc.count ?? 0).Sum(),

    available = (totalUnits - sold - writtenOff - onDisplay),
};
```

The "available" column at the end doesn't work, but I've included it to illustrate what I'm trying to acheive - a column calculated from the columns already generated. Is this possible? I could do it at the presentation layer, but wanted to check if this would work first.

Also - to my (new to Linq) eye, the query looks inefficient as I am repeating myself in generating the writtenOff and sold columns. Is there a better way to acheive this when I have aggregate functions involved.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

One more thing - I only want to return rows where "available" is > 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do a second select new {} for the last line (you'll have to copy again all the fields you need in that second select) and after that add a where clause

EDIT: not really related, but it looks like you could benefit from a new column holding the available value (with Linq To Sql and INotityPropertyChanging, it should be quite easy to implement)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a query that should do what you want.

(Note: this assumes that you've set up an association between `Product` -> `Purchases` -> `BoxContents` in your DBML designer.)

```
var query = from product in context.Products
            where 
            (
                product.Purchases.Count() * product.units -
                product.Purchases.Sum(purchase => purchase.soldUnits ?? 0) -
                product.Purchases.Sum(purchase => purchase.woUnits ?? 0) -
                product.Purchases.SelectMany(purchase => purchase.BoxContents).Sum(bc => bc.count ?? 0)
            ) > 0
            select product;
```

And, FYI, here's one way you could set up your `Product` class.

(You might want to use [`DataLoadOptions.LoadWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534268.aspx) to eager-load `Product`'s children.)

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int TotalUnits
    {
        get { return this.Purchases.Count * this.units ?? 0; }
    }

    public int Sold
    {
        get { return this.Purchases.Sum(p => p.soldUnits ?? 0); }
    }

    public int WrittenOff
    {
        get { return this.Purchases.Sum(p => p.woUnits ?? 0); }
    }

    public int OnDisplay
    {
        get { return this.Purchases.SelectMany(p => p.BoxContents).Sum(b => b.count ?? 0); }
    }

    public int Available
    {
        get { return TotalUnits - Sold - WrittenOff - OnDisplay; }
    }
}
```